# Different behavior of Autofac depending of usage of builder.Register or builder.RegisterType

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

With a specific (complex) nesting of classes, I encounter an exception at runtime in Autofac when I attempt to resolve a type registered with

`builder.RegisterType<ClassThatDoesNotWork>().UsingConstructor(expression);`

But the same registration works with :

`builder.Register<ClassThatDoesNotWork>(func);`

Adding `.As<MyType>` does not appear to change anything.

I can't figure if it's a PEBKAC or a bug. Additionnally, I have found > `builder.RegisterType<T>().UsingConstructor(expression);` to work in some other cases.

I made a full working example (sorry, it's a bit long, but the problem disappears if I use a too simple structure) :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1");
        //var b = InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType2");
        var c = InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>();
        var e = InjectionConfig.Resolve<ClassThatWorks>();

        // This one will fail
        var f = InjectionConfig.Resolve<ClassThatDoesNotWork>();
    }
}

public static class InjectionConfig
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; }

    static InjectionConfig()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModule<InitModule>();

        Container = builder.Build();
    }

    public static TService Resolve<TService>()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<TService>();
    }

    public static TService ResolveNamed<TService>(string dependancy)
    {
        return Container.ResolveNamed<TService>(dependancy);
    }
}

public class InitModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        RegisterTemplateServices(builder);

        RegisterPropertiesGenerationServices(builder);
    }

    private void RegisterTemplateServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var myServiceType1 = new WhateverService("MyServiceType1");
        builder.RegisterInstance(myServiceType1).Keyed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1").SingleInstance();

        //var myServiceType2 = new WhateverService("MyServiceType2");
        //builder.RegisterInstance(myServiceType2).Keyed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType2").SingleInstance();
    }

    private void RegisterPropertiesGenerationServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        Func<IComponentContext, RandomInnerClass> funCtorRandomInnerClass =
            context => new RandomInnerClass(InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
        builder.Register<RandomInnerClass>(funCtorRandomInnerClass).As<RandomInnerClass>();

        // This kind of initialization works
        Func<IComponentContext, ClassThatWorks> funcWorks = context => new ClassThatWorks(new AnotherClass(InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>()), InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
        builder.Register<ClassThatWorks>(funcWorks);

        // This one FAILS at runtime
        Expression<Func<ClassThatDoesNotWork>> expressionDoesNotWork = () => new ClassThatDoesNotWork(new AnotherClass(InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>()), InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
        builder.RegisterType<ClassThatDoesNotWork>().UsingConstructor(expressionDoesNotWork);

        // It would work if instead for registration I used :
        // Func<IComponentContext, ClassThatDoesNotWork> funcExample = context => new ClassThatDoesNotWork(new AnotherClass(InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>()), InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
        //builder.Register<ClassThatDoesNotWork>(funcExample);
    }
}

internal class AnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass(RandomInnerClass resolve) { }
}

internal class ClassThatDoesNotWork
{
    public ClassThatDoesNotWork(AnotherClass a, WhateverService b) { }
}

internal class ClassThatWorks
{
    public ClassThatWorks(AnotherClass a, WhateverService b) { }
}

internal class RandomInnerClass
{
    public RandomInnerClass(WhateverService a) { }
}

internal class WhateverService
{
    public WhateverService(string myIdentifier) { }
}
```

The exception :

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during
>   the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception
>   for details. Registration: Activator = ClassThatDoesNotWork
>   (ReflectionActivator), Services = [ConsoleApp1.ClassThatDoesNotWork],
>   Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None,
>   Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found
>   with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on
>   type 'ConsoleApp1.ClassThatDoesNotWork' can be invoked with the
>   available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'ConsoleApp1.AnotherClass a' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(ConsoleApp1.AnotherClass, ConsoleApp1.WhateverService)'. (See
>   inner exception for details.) --->
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors
>   found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'ConsoleApp1.ClassThatDoesNotWork' can be invoked with the available
>   services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'ConsoleApp1.AnotherClass a' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(ConsoleApp1.AnotherClass, ConsoleApp1.WhateverService)'.    à
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne --- 
>   à Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)    à Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()    à
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) 
>   à Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    à
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext
>   context)    à ConsoleApp1.InjectionConfig.ResolveTService dans
>   T:\Temp\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:ligne 55    à
>   ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) dans
>   T:\Temp\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:ligne 27

As you can see in the middle, using

```
Func<IComponentContext, ClassThatDoesNotWork> funcExample = context => new ClassThatDoesNotWork(new AnotherClass(InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>()), InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
builder.Register<ClassThatDoesNotWork>(funcExample);
```

instead of

```
Expression<Func<ClassThatDoesNotWork>> expressionDoesNotWork = () => new ClassThatDoesNotWork(new AnotherClass(InjectionConfig.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>()), InjectionConfig.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1"));
builder.RegisterType<ClassThatDoesNotWork>().UsingConstructor(expressionDoesNotWork);
```

fixes the problem. *For me* both constructs should do the same, but not.

I'm using autofac 4.8.1 (last) in .Net 4.6.2.

I would like to know if I do something bad, and additionnally what's the best between the two constructs (for performance concerns, etc).
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the way you register components looks way overcomplicated for no good reason. With all this pile of `new WhateverClass()` you seem to be doing Autofac's job for it, especially considering that Autofac is complaining that you're doing it not entirely correctly. In my opinion this can be done much simpler.

But even if we set this apart, there's more serious problem with your code. Using static `InjectionConfig` in resolving everything inside your registrations you're effectively breaking Autofac's lifetime scope management. This is exactly what is not supposed to be done when using Autofac. If you need to resolve something in registration lambda then you should use IComponentContext that Autofac provides.

So, what I'd do instead is below. If this does not work for some reason then let's find what does.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule<InitModule>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var a = scope.ResolveNamed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1");
            var c = scope.Resolve<RandomInnerClass>();
            var e = scope.Resolve<ClassThatWorks>();

            // This one now works
            var f = scope.Resolve<ClassThatDoesNotWork>();
        }
    }
}

public class InitModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        RegisterTemplateServices(builder);

        RegisterPropertiesGenerationServices(builder);
    }

    private void RegisterTemplateServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<WhateverService>()
            .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("myIdentifier", "MyServiceType1"))
            .Named<WhateverService>("MyServiceType1")
            .AsSelf()
            .SingleInstance();

        //var myServiceType2 = new WhateverService("MyServiceType2");
        //builder.RegisterInstance(myServiceType2).Keyed<WhateverService>("MyServiceType2").SingleInstance();
    }

    private void RegisterPropertiesGenerationServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<AnotherClass>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<RandomInnerClass>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassThatWorks>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ClassThatDoesNotWork>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

internal class AnotherClass
{
    public AnotherClass(RandomInnerClass resolve)
    {
    }
}

internal class ClassThatDoesNotWork
{
    public ClassThatDoesNotWork(AnotherClass a, [KeyFilter("MyServiceType1")] WhateverService b)
    {
    }
}

internal class ClassThatWorks
{
    public ClassThatWorks(AnotherClass a, [KeyFilter("MyServiceType1")] WhateverService b)
    {
    }
}

internal class RandomInnerClass
{
    public RandomInnerClass([KeyFilter("MyServiceType1")] WhateverService a)
    {
    }
}

internal class WhateverService
{
    public WhateverService(string myIdentifier)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding general practices : the real world program is more complex than first post, and requires to be able to use the "full constructor delegate" as I did in my sample. Most of the time I attempt to simply use "RegisterType" and let Autofac resolve itself arguments of ctor. I was already using "WithParameter" when possible. I was not aware of attribute "KeyFilter", I don't really like to introduce inside my code attributes related to DI, but it could help, thanks for it.
I have replaced static calls to Container by "context.Resolve" when possible.

Comment: Regarding my problem : I will always use lifetime scope even if I don't care about it, and I will avoid usage of RegisterType for such complex calls (when I need to resolve something inside my constructor, like I did with my calls to my container). I see why RegisterType failed in my case. Thanks for proposals !

Comment: Since the code is pretty big and there's lot of stuff going on - please answer couple of questions: did my answer really help you and in what way exactly?